# Create nested forms using Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm trying to build a nested form using Devise, keeping the devise featuring as sending an email when a new user signs up. I would like to have something like this:

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <%= f.fields_for(:information) do |info| %>

    <div><%= info.text_field :name, :placeholder => 'Nome' %></div>

    <div><%= info.text_field :surname, :placeholder => 'Cognome' %></div>

  <% end %>


  <div><%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true, :placeholder => 'E-mail' %></div>

  <div><%= f.password_field :password, :placeholder => 'Password' %></div>

  <div><%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, :placeholder => 'Conferma password' %></div>

  <div><%= f.submit "Registrati", class: "btn btn-large btn-info" %></div>
<% end %>
```

In my `route.rb`

`devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "users" }`

In my `user.rb`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :information, dependent: :destroy
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, 
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable,
     :validatable, :confirmable, :lockable

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :information, update_only: true
end
```

and in `information.rb`

```
class Information < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

in `users_controller.rb`

```
class UsersController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def new
super
resource.build_information
  end

end
```

But nothing happen, or better the 2 fields `name` and `surname` don't appear, but I don't receive an error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I would do,

**I would move this line from the controller to the view(fields_for takes 2 parameters).** Like below,

Controller

```
def new
   super
   resource.build_information #remove from here
end
```

View

```
<!--Added here -->
<%= f.fields_for(:information,resource.build_information) do |info| %>
```

**Must work now!**

OR

Just change
`<%= form_for(resource, :as => res.....`
to

```
<%= form_for(@resource, :as => res
```

**Note "@", this will work. Remove build_information both from view and controller.**

Comment: Yeah, it worked. Just one question, why wasn't my solution good? where was the problem?

Comment: Instead of explaining. Let me serve you with a food for thought. "resource is not an instance variable". Check out my edit.

Comment: I know `resource` is a method
    def resource
      @resource ||= User.new
    end

But it returns the @resource instance...so I thought that calling `resource.build_information` should have worked

Comment: Dude, a = 1 in controller wont print 1 if you did <%= a %> in your view, @a = 1 in controller will print 1 if you did <%= @a %> in your view. Ok I mean the resource.build_information that you did in the controller is lost in the view.

Comment: It's obvious. I try to explain my thought
In the `new` action I called `resource` to set `@resource`, after I set it because @resource is an instance variable I can access it from the view, so if in the view I call `resource` should I get the same instance variable (`@resource`) set before?

Comment: Edit: I tryed to set in the controller le following variable `@test = "hello"` and then I tryed to access it from the view `<%= @test %>` but nothing is shown, how is that?